# end string and create new column in csv - javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So im extracting data and im trying to clean it up before saving it into a csv, I managed to get the following line in my csv to separate into 2 columns,

name and address = column 1
contact info = column 2

I want to separate the emails and telephone in the second column into their own columns. Ive tried replacing the word "**E-Mail**" with a comma, it does work by replacing the word with a comma but its not creating a new column in my csv im not sure why?

```
var newStr = str.replace(/E-Mail:/g, ",");
```

After running the piece of code above i get this ouput in my csv file

"Dave Smith 1234 honey st Alchemy Way Liverpool L65 123 United Kingdom "," Telefon:01744|236691 ,ebay.dk@gmail.com"

Comment: i don't thing _str_ is defined correctly, you can't use a comma in the middle of a string literal...

Comment: i copied the str data from my csv file through notepad, it has commas to define new colums. Thats not how it actually looks in my javascript file sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Could you give the actual version of your javascript file so  that we can help you ?

Comment: i edited my post and made it more clear, you can see after running the regex it removed the word "E-Mail:" and replaced it with a comma but its not creating a new column in my csv file.